# Make Paraview animation by changing the data on a fixed geometry

Tags: animation, visualization, paraview

I wish to construct an animation in Paraview starting from some files obtained in an optimization process. I have a mesh made of tetrahedrons and at each iteration I have a scalar field on this mesh.

I could create a VTK file for each iteration, but such a file is larger than 100Mb and it would take more than 15GB to store all the vtk files. Moreover, the geometry part in each vtk file is the same, so I guess there is a more efficient solution. Therefore my question:

> Is it possible to make animations in Paraview by changing a scalar field on a fixed geometry?

(if this is not the right forum to ask this, please let me know where it could be more appropriate)

Comment: As you note, with VTK files you have to re-specify the scalar field for each time step. If you want to save memory, you have to move to a different file format that allows you to have time varying fields on a fixed geometry. For changing fields on unstructured grids, we often use the Exodus II file format. I believe the XDMF format also allows you to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your indication. I will try to use other formats.